# [ReferenceError]: window is not defined

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js, java-14

I have an object `Window` in scalajs:

```
@js.native
@JSGlobalScope
object Window extends js.Object {
  def window: Int = js.native
}
```

And I am using `window` as follows:

```
val text: Option[String] =
  for {
    window <- Option(Window.window)
    windowStr <- Option(window.toString)
  } yield windowStr
```

I am getting the following error:

```
/path/to/target/scala-2.13/myModule-fastopt.js:111
  const value = window;

ReferenceError: window is not defined
...
```

I am using:

- ScalaJS - v1.1.1
- Scala - 2.13.3
- SBT - 1.3.13
- Java - OpenJDK v14.0.2

Comment: Apologies. I forgot to add the proper code. Edited my code.

Comment: What behavior were you expecting? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your `for` still makes no sense. If `Window.window` is supposed to be an `Int` then it can never be `null` so wrapping it in an `Option` doesn't accomplish anything. You might as well write `val text = Some(window.toString)` and be done with it.

Comment: I know. But why I am getting `ReferenceError` for it? That is my main problem, not the code style.